# netbeans 12.0 print and println

Tags: java, netbeans

Our university chooses netbeans IDE in our OOP java, my question is why did it not print `System.out.print("Input number: ");` first in this code snippet

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){    
      Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("number inputted is " + num);
    }
}
```

here is the output
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWwfG.png)

but when I change the line to  `System.out.println` this is the output[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6gnK.png)

is this some netbeans stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It is running absolutely fine in my netbeans.
Re install it there might be any changes at the time of installation
Now if you are beginner you can practice java in bluej.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to re install NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

If you want the stuff
"number inputted is n" in the next line, then add println to the 4th line of your program.
This is your required code:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main (String[] args){    
          Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);    
            System.out.println("Input number: ");
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("number inputted is " + num);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: We use println to make the cursor move down, to the next line after the text is printed.
For eg.-

```
public class Main {
            public static void main (String[] args){      
                System.out.print("Input number:);
                System.out.println("number inputted is " );
            }
        }
```

prints:
Input number:number inputted is

What the above code does is that it also shifts the cursor down to the next line in the terminal, so that the next line you print is printed in the next line.
but,

```
public class Main {
                public static void main (String[] args){      
                    System.out.println("Input number:);
                    System.out.print("number inputted is " );
                }
            }
```

this prints:
Input number:
number inputted is

I hope it is clear to you!!